# Call GNU Make from AucTeX

Tags: emacs, auctex, makefile

In most Emacs major modes targetting compiled programming languages, <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> invokes `make`. In AucTeX, it lets me choose between any of

```
BibTeX  Biber   Check   ChkTeX  Clean   Clean All   File
Index   LaTeX   Other   Print   Queue   Spell   View
Xindy
```

These options are generally fine, but sometimes compiling my document requires more complex steps; in these cases, I use a Makefile.

**How can I extend the list displayed by AucTeX to include a `Make` option?**

`TeX-command-list` and `TeX-run-compile` seem relevant, as <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> invokes `TeX-command-master`, which presents entries from `TeX-command-list.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it's a duplicate, but the answer is there.

Comment: As an aside, I'd recommend using arara instead of a Makefile (`texdoc arara`)